# SwiftUI foreground/background order with .primary

Tags: swiftui

Given this View definition:

```
struct ContentView: View {
    var body: some View {
        VStack {
            Text("yellow on black")
                .foregroundColor(.yellow)
                .background(.black)
            Text("yellow on black")
                .background(.black)
                .foregroundColor(.yellow)
            Text("yellow on black")
                .foregroundColor(.yellow)
                .background(.primary)
            Text("yellow on black")
                .background(.primary)
                .foregroundColor(.yellow)
        }
    }
}
```

And this result:

[image: preview]

Can anyone explain why the last Text is yellow on yellow?

Comment: That is an odd result.  Note that the `.primary` you are getting in the last two is `HierarchicalShapeStyle.primary` and not `Color.primary` as you might expect.  That is because `background()` takes more than just a `Color`.  If you use `background(Color.primary)` you get the result you expect.

Comment: Interesting, I would have expected the compiler to complain that it's ambiguous. Thank you!